# Akka and two-way actor conversations

Tags: synchronization, akka, messaging, actor

Akka-based actor messaging feels like a one-way stream/flow of messages from some "upstream" actor to one or more "downstream" actors.

But there might be a legitimate use case for some kind of two-way (request/response) synchronous messaging between two actors. For instance, I might have a `CacheActor` that manages some cache. Other actors might want to `put` and `get` cache entries to this cache, and they need to do so through `CacheActor`:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class CacheActor extends UntypedActor {
    Map<String,Object> cache

    // ...

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof GetCacheEntry) {
            GetCacheEntry getCacheEntry = message as GetCacheEntry
            String entry = cache.get(getCacheEntry.key)

            // Now what? How to send back to the actor that called this?!?
            getCacheEntry.sender.tell(new GetCacheEntryResult(getCacheEntry.buzz, entry))   // <-- 2. return to sender (again with 'buzz' as sidecar)
        }
    }
}

class FizzActor extends UntypedActor {
    ActorRef cacheActor

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof Buzz) {
            Buzz buzz = message as Buzz
            cacheActor.tell(new GetCacheEntry(buzz, this))  // <-- 1. identify 'this' as the sender and pass 'buzz' in as sidecar
        } else if(message instanceof GetCacheEntryResult) { // <-- 3. recognize that we are processing the result from #1 above
            GetCacheEntryResult result = message as GetCacheEntryResult
            Buzz originalBuzz = result.buzz
            String resultantEntry = result.entry

            // 4. Now keep processing...
        }
    }
}
```

This is the only way I can envision passing messages back and forth between two actors in a "conversational" request-response style. The problem with it is that its a bit nasty:

- I have to create new message types (e.g. `GetCacheEntryResult`) for each response sent back to the requester, which will quickly bloat the code; and
- Each time one actor responds to another, all of the "*context variables*" that are "in scope" likely need to be bundled up and sent back to the requesting actor as sidecars, so that they are available to the requester when they receive the answer and need to continue processing (see `buzz` below). In a more complicated orchestration between *several* actors, this "context map" is going to get fairly big; and
- At the end of the day, this solution just *feels* like code smell to me...

So I ask: **is there a better way to do this in Akka? Maybe using `Futures` or the `ask(...)` method?**

Comment: maybe include ref to sending actor in the GetCacheEntry structure?

Comment: That's a great idea @AlexeiKaigorodov (+1) - but it comes with its own set of headaches (please see my update). Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Why don't you read about actor asking? http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#Use_with_Actors

Comment: Thanks @Quizzie (+1) - I did read that, but because the examples are all in Scala its difficult to see how they translate to the Java API. More importantly, those examples only show you how to *call* `ask(...)` from the "client-side", not how the other actor (the one being asked) actually responds to `ask(...)` and passes the message back to the requester. Ideas?

Comment: The link I posted was in Java, so read it again. It is very useful. Asking works like this: someone asks actorA  with messageA. The sender of this message is a new unique temporary ActorRef used only for this ask. Then actorA will receive messageA and can reply to the sender of the message with messageB. This reply is automatically mapped into a future. You can specify a timeout for how long you are willing to wait for the reply. If the sender is an actor, the reply will be received independently on his mailbox.